# Excel vsto add-in sheet1 sheet2 sheet3

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, add-in

[image]

[image: 2]

I have the Excel vsto add-in code, but I can only use it in sheet1,
I ask is how to make my Excel vsto add-in code, work in sheet1, sheet2, sheet3.

Comment: First of all - edit your answer as [it should be](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Second, at a glance, your code will work on the active sheet and it wouldn't care whether it is sheet1, sheet2 or sheet3.

Comment: thank you for answering,You have a solution to enable and disable the addin via vba excel ? https://i.imgur.com/fqcus8r.jpg

Comment: Site rules: include code as text, not as an image. Images are difficult to read, at best, and the content cannot be copied/pasted for testing purposes. As best I can tell, the bit of code shown is not relevant to the problem. Include code relevant to the problem and explain how it's "not working".

Answer (score 0):

I had the same struggle, understanding how the freak i call the excel objects. Well thru globals mainly.

```
Dim Xlwb as excel.Workbook =Globals.thisaddin.application.activeworkbook '(or thisworkbook)

Dim xlws as excel.worksheet = xlwb.Activesheet
```

That usually works for me in vb should be about ghe same.
For c# is..

Excel.Workbook xlwb = globals... And so on.
I can't

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to call Excel objects:

```
Excel.Application ExApp=new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook ExWB = ExApp.Workbooks.Open(FileName, ReadOnly: true);
Excel._Worksheet ExWS= ExWB.Sheets[1];
```

If you work only with your workbook, you can use the following instructions to call worksheets and a cell:

```
Sheet1 wsMain = Globals.Sheet1;
wsMain.Range["A1"].Value2 = Value;
```